# Combining multiple extension methods in loop

Tags: c#

I have a the following class:

```
public class Datum
{
    public DateTime DateTime;
    public double Value;
}
```

With these extension methods:

```
 public static double Sum(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this)
    {
        return @this.Sum(datum => datum.Value);
    }


 public static IEnumerable<Datum> InTimeRange(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        return from datum in @this
               where (start <= datum.DateTime && datum.DateTime < end)  
               select datum;
    }

 public static IEnumerable<Datum> ForEach(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this, object businesshours)
    {

        var pob = businesshours.ToString();
        switch(pob)
        {
            case "business": 
                return from datum in @this
                       where (datum.DateTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday & datum.DateTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday & datum.DateTime.Hour > 7 & datum.DateTime.Hour < 20)
                       select datum;

            case "offhours": 
                return from datum in @this
                       where !(datum.DateTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday & datum.DateTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday & datum.DateTime.Hour > 7 & datum.DateTime.Hour < 20)
                       select datum;
             default:
                return from datum in @this
                       select datum;
        }
    }

public static IEnumerable<Datum> Addition(this IEnumerable<Datum> @this, double val)
    {
        foreach (var datum in @this)
        {
            datum.Value += val;
        }
        return @this;
    }
```

If I want to sum over all business hours I can do:

```
somelist.ForEach(busineshourindicator).InTimeRange(startdate, enddate).Sum();
```

this works without any problem and if businessindicator = "business" it sums only over business hours in given time range.

However, if I want to combine all of this in a for loop and combine multiple numbers in one hourly schedule (like this):

```
        public static double[] hourlyvec(double[] DelStart, double[] DelEnd, double[] position, object[] businessindicator, double PosStart, double PosEnd)
    {
        double nrhrs = (PosEnd - PosStart + 1) * 24;

        List<Datum> result = new List<Datum>();
        double tempdate = PosStart;
        for (int i = 0; i < nrhrs; ++i)
        {
            result.Add(new Datum { DateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(tempdate), Value = 0 });
            tempdate += (1 / 24);
        }


        for (int k = 0; k < DelStart.Length; k++)
        {
            result.ForEach(businessindicator[k]).InTimeRange(DateTime.FromOADate(DelStart[k]), DateTime.FromOADate(DelEnd[k])).Addition(position[k]);
        }

        return result.todoub().ToArray();

    }
```

This fails. Quick example of what I would expect:

First row:
Delstart = 3/1/13, DelEnd = 4/1/13, Businessindicator ="Business", Position = 100

Second row:
Delstart = 3/1/13, DelEnd = 4/1/13, Businessindicator ="Offhours", Position = 50

Thrid row:
Delstart = 3/1/13, DelEnd = 4/1/13, Businessindicator ="ALL", Position = 75

Posstart = 3/1/13, PosEnd = 4/1/13

Then the function should return hourly vector with 24 hrs where hours 1-8 = 125, hours 9-20=175, and the remaining hours again 125.

All of these extension methods seem to work on an individual basis but when I combine them in a loop I dont get the right answer.

Sorry for the wordy post, I hope it is clear what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: `I don't get the right answer.`  What answer do you get?

Comment: I just get the same number for all hours, as if the destinction between business hours and offhours doesnt work, but it does work correctly when I combine it with the SUM() method

Comment: You shouldn't be causing side effects in query operators.  `Addition` shouldn't be changing the items provided, it should be creating an entirely new sequence that has new items that are the result of adding a value to each item.  All of your other operators are (correctly) side effect free.  The `ForEach` operator isn't really properly named though.  You're not doing something *for each* item, you're actually filtering it where it meets some condition...

Comment: @Servy: thanks, I get your point. But how do I then pass the newly created list to the next iteration of the loop? or do you recommend creating one vector for each iteration of the loop and then add them all up afterwards?

Comment: @npvh Your `Addition` can be implemented using `Select`.  You'll want to create a new `Datum` for each previous one, and set the value of the new `Datum` to be the value of the previous, plus something.  `return @this.Select(d => new Datum(){DateTime = d.DateTime, Value = d.Value + val});`

Comment: @Servy: If I use this:   return @this.Select(d => new Datum(){DateTime = d.DateTime, Value = d.Value + val}); as Addition extension method then a loop over this returns zeros, i.e. someList.Addition(5) returns zero. Or would I have to pass this to new list also, like datum newlist = somelist.Addition(5)?